# How to prevent the react components ui initial rendering on the page without styled-components loaded

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, components, styled-components

I have a custom component `React` library built with `styled-components` for some of the reusable components.
In the same repo, I import the custom component library into my `nextJS` project and use the components.

However, any styles in the custom component library that's created with `styled-components` are not included in the initial render of the page, but any other **inline** `react` styles are included on initial render.

**Question:
Are there any ways to prevent the components ui rendered on the page without any styles loaded, specifically those styles created using styled-components in my custom component react library.**

I'm using static html export for my nextJS project and deploy to cdn like cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

`styled-components` approach is a baked style approach, which means the style you use stays local to that component. Therefore there's no way to strip them out. The original css approach is a global style approach, which can be enabled or disabled. Hope that makes some sense.

For a styled components to switch to another set of styles ,please search `theme` topic for `styled-components`.